# Clarification on synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, parallel-processing

Lets say I have a class that has two methods `calculateBonus(Account a)` and `calculatePenalty(Account a)`.

Lets say I add the `synchronized` keyword to the methods or have a `synchronized(this)` block inside the methods.  Does this effectively mean that if a thread is calculating a bonus on an account no other thread can calculate a penalty on a different account until the bonus is done?

Penalties and bonuses are varied and complex, it is possible that an account may receive both.  It does not matter what order they are calculated (there is a cutoff date so one does not affect the outcome of the other) but it is critical that I do not attempt to calculate both on the same account at the same time (for obvious data consistency reasons, there are statuses and audit trail information being updated inside of each method).

What would be the best way to design my code so that I can SAFELY maximize parallel processing?

I have considered these options so far:

1) Put the code that calculates bonuses and penalties in different classes and use the `synchronized` key word on the method.  Don't like this idea because there are some shared complex functions that I would like to keep together, they are not IO bound and execute quickly so do not impact performance.

2) Synchronize on the passed in `Account` parameter.  If I understand this correctly that means that I can not calculate a bonus on another account executing in another thread until the bonus is calculated on the first account in the first thread.  But I could calculate a penalty on a different account in a different thread - just not the **same** account.  I like this one the most but want to be sure I understand it correctly.

3) Create an internal private lock object for each method that I want to synchronize, one for bonuses and one for penalties.  If understand this correctly it means that only one thread can be calculating a bonus at a time but it **does not** prevent another thread from calculating a penalty on the **same** account at the same time.

Now I understand that I have to be careful to avoid deadlock, I plan to make sure that nothing inside any synchronized block depends on calls to other synchronized methods.  I also intend to make sure that any local variable used in a calculation that affects the final value is inside the synchronized block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think option 2 - or a variant on it - is your best bet, but I think you're still misunderstanding it slightly:

> Synchronize on the passed in Account parameter. If I understand this correctly that means that I can not calculate a bonus on another account executing in another thread until the bonus is calculated on the first account in the first thread.

No - it means that:

- You won't be able to calculate either a bonus *or* a penalty on the *same* account, because your thread is holding the monitor for that account.
- Any thread can calculate a bonus or a penalty on a *different* account though, because that will have a different monitor.

Now typically I don't like locking on any publicly-visible reference (such as the Account parameter) because it makes it harder to reason about the locking. It would normally be preferable for each `Account` instance to have its own object used just for locking, e.g.

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
```

and for instance methods in `Account` to lock on that... but if you can't put the methods in `Account`, you can't really do that. Perhaps these methods *should* be in `Account` though? Perhaps you should change the responsibility - so that you have `Account.calculateBonus(BonusFormula)` and `Account.calculatePenalty(PenaltyFormula)` or something similar?

It's hard to say for sure without knowing more details, but it generally *feels* like the lock should only be known to the object which is performing the synchronization.

Comment: Man you are fast!  You replied 4 minutes after I posted!  So does that mean that two or more threads can be calculating a bonus on different accounts at the same time?  Because I have local variables holding information if an other thread can jump in it would alter these values and when the first thread resumes it would be working with corrupted data.  How can I avoid that?

Comment: @BigMac66: If you lock on some object, nothing which also locks on this object can be done at the same time.  Local variables are local to each invocation of a method, and thus are not changed by other threads.

Comment: @BigMac66: Yes, different threads would be able to calculate bonuses at the same time... but *local* variables aren't shared between threads. (Of course, if these local variables in different threads refer to an modify the same objects, then you could have problems.)

Comment: Interesting it appears I can view answers-in-progress, my comment above was based on your incomplete answer, because what I see now is different.

Comment: @BigMac66: It was my originally-submitted answer, which I then edited.

Comment: OK then this is better than I first thought!  If local variables aren't shared (especially those whose scope is limited to the synchronized block) then I can be calculating several bonuses at once!  Essentially I only want one thread to be able to make **any** kind of modification to an account at a time, so if I lock on the 'Account' object I believe I can achieve that.  Since I am dealing with lots of accounts I want to base my synchronization scheme on the account and not the calculations/formulas (hope that makes sense).  Thanks - things are much clearer now regarding local variables!